# urlencode UTF-8 для safari?

Tags: php, url, iframe, youtube, safari

Youtube в firefox,opera,IE принимает строки url на поиск в кодировке utf8.
А если запрашивать через safari то работает только в CP1251

```
Так в firefox работает
http://www.youtube.com/embed?listType=search&list=%D0%A1%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F+%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B8

Так в safari не работает - выводит ошибки перебирая разные файлы
http://www.youtube.com/embed?listType=search&list=%D0%A1%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F+%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B8

Так в safari работает - если на английском передать
http://www.youtube.com/embed?listType=search&list=russia team

Так в safari работает - если кодировать urlencode из 1251
 http://www.youtube.com/embed?listType=search&list=%D0%A0%D0%8E%D0%A0%C2%B1%D0%A0%D1%95%D0%A1%D0%82%D0%A0%D0%85%D0%A0%C2%B0%D0%A1%D0%8F+%D0%A1%D0%82%D0%A0%D1%95%D0%A1%D0%83%D0%A1%D0%83%D0%A0%D1%91%D0%A0%D1%91



  <?php 
    $text = "Сборная россии"; 
    //$text = urlencode($text); // работает в других браузерах кроме safari
    $text = urlencode(mb_convert_encoding($text,"UTF-8", "CP1251")); // работает в safari после перекодировки

    echo "<pre>".$text."</pre>";
    echo "<iframe src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed?listType=search&list=".$text."\"  frameborder=\"0\"  ></iframe>";
?>
```

Есть ли универсальное средство по передаче ссылок url в utf8, чтобы работало во всех браузерах?